# How do you set the name of the iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store

I have released and updated a few apps now, but this is still not very clear.

The app name as it appears on the app store is set from iTunes connect. Where do you set the name of the app as it appears on the phone once it is installed?

I have tried and succeeded in setting it in 'Product Name', but when Product Name has a space in it, the binary file name has a space too, which is not allowed when you upload the binary.

Clarity on this issue would be great.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Developing in Android, when first creating the application, you can set the name of the app from there. Also you can edit the name through its manifest XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just manually remove the space in the binary's filename before you upload it to iTunes Connect. It doesn't affect your app's name when installed on devices.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Info.plist` file you can set the name that appears on the iPhone screen. The setting you need is called "Bundle display name" and it starts out set to `${PRODUCT_NAME}`. Set it to whatever you like.

If you want to change the name according to the users language, create a file called `InfoPlist.strings` and localize it. I've made a Japanese localization (ja) for my app and the file contains one line:

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "東京アート";
```

This means that users with their locale set to Japan see that name, and other users see the one in `Info.plist`

If you Get Info on the Target, you can also set the "Product Name", which is the name you end up with after building (the actual file). You can set it with no spaces. You can also just remove the space before you zip and upload.